# Unable to update the Facebook Ad Creative data with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-nodejs-business-sdk

In my NodeJS application have used "facebook-nodejs-business-sdk" package for Facebook Ads Creation, I can create the Facebook Carousel Ad with AdCreative, But I unable to update the Ad Creative Data.